# I keep getting "KeyError" I've tested by printing each side of the if statement but no luck

Tags: python, keyerror

I keep getting "KeyError" I've tested by printing each side of the if statement but no luck.

```
def colapse():
  queue = []
  colapsed = random.choice(idMinEntrepy(board))
  check = random.choice(range(len(board[colapsed[0]][colapsed[1]])))
  board[colapsed[0]][colapsed[1]] = board[colapsed[0]][colapsed[1]][check]
  queue.append(colapsed)
  while len(queue)>0:
    for pos in ((1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)):
      valids = []
      if -1 < queue[0][0]+pos[0] < domain[1] and -1 < queue[0][1]+pos[1] < domain[0]:
        #here are my tested that did not result in the "KeyError"
        #print(board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check].get("code")[yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])])
        #print(board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check].get("code")[yxtosideindex(pos[0], pos[1])])
        # here's the issue \/ \/ \/
        if board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check].get("code")[yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])] == board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check].get("code")[yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])]:
          valids.append(board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]])
    queue.append((queue[0][0]+pos[0],queue[0][1]+pos[1]))
    board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]] = valids
    queue.pop(0)
```

My code needs to compare the two and contue with the program if they are same, but i keep getting the same error. the "code" lable exists in both and the defention of both are arrays with 4 int's
ex. [100, 100, 100, 100],
[0,   1,   0,   1  ]

Comment: You're making us guess what/where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the KeyError is being raised when you try to access the code field of a dictionary using the get method. This error occurs when the key you are trying to access does not exist in the dictionary.

One possible cause of this error could be that the dictionary you are trying to access does not have a code key. You can fix this by adding a check to see if the code key exists in the dictionary before trying to access it:

```
if "code" in board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check] and "code" in board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check]:
    if board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check]["code"][yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])] == board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check]["code"][yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])]:
        valids.append(board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]])
```

Another possible cause of this error could be that the yxtosideindex function is returning a value that is not a valid index for the code list. You can fix this by adding a check to make sure that the value returned by yxtosideindex is a valid index for the code list:

```
index = yxtosideindex(pos[0],pos[1])
if index >= 0 and index < len(board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check]["code"]) and index >= 0 and index < len(board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check]["code"]):
    if board[queue[0][0]][queue[0][1]][check]["code"][index] == board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]][check]["code"][index]:
        valids.append(board[queue[0][0]+pos[0]][queue[0][1]+pos[1]])
```

Comment: `.get()` will not raise a KeyError.